# Using DATEPART into a Slick Query

Tags: sql-server, scala, slick, datepart

I am trying to use DATEPART into a slick query to give me a sum of values in every month of the year. For doing so, I am trying the following query:

```
val empenhado = tableReference.filter(_.cancelled.isEmpty)
                                  .filter(_.unidadeGestora like unidadeGestora)
                                  .filter(_.confirmado)
                                  .filter(_.anoEmissao === now.get(Calendar.YEAR))
                                  .filterNot(_.id in queryEstornado)
                                      .groupBy(r => datePart("mm",r.dataEmissao))
                                        .map(r => (r._1, r._2.map(r2 => r2.valorEmpenhado).sum))

    empenhado.run
```

When I try to run it, I get the error:

> [SQLException: Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart.]

I've defined the datePart function as:

```
protected val datePart = SimpleFunction.binary[String,Date,Int]("DATEPART")
```

And the date attribute is called dataEmissao and it is mapped as *java.sql.Date*

How can I correctly pass the parameters to DATEPART ?

**UPDATE**

I checked the SQL statement generated by slick and I noticed that it tries to pass the parameter to DATEPART as:

> DATEPART('mm',x2."data_emissao")

while it should be:

> DATEPART(mm,x2."data_emissao")

How can I pass **mm** instead of **'mm'** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
datePart("mm"
```

Should be

```
datePart(mm
```

Comment: Hi! it would be like this if it was pure SQL. I am using a scala function mapped to SQL function. If I try to use mm instead of "mm", the code does not compile because mm is not defined.

Comment: you area correct, but how can I pass it to SQL through slick without the ' ' ??